# How do i foreach from database to verify login in Android

Tags: android

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Login",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                            List<String[]> data = userData.selectAll();
                            String iUsername = inputUsername.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            String iPassword = inputPassword.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            if (data != null) {

                                for (String[] username : data) {

                                    if (iUsername
                                            .equals(username[1])
                                            && iPassword
                                                    .equals(username[2])) {

                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Welcome " + username[1],
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        System.out.println("----------------->"+username[2]);
                                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                                MainActivity.this,
                                                SelectMenuZone.class);
                                        i.putExtra("Username", username[1]);
                                        i.putExtra("userID", username[4]);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {

                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Username or Password Incorrect",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

My project have to login to identify user, there many user in database i will verify the only one user in database

this code will foreach the all of data in database to verify username and password, how do i verify only one data that correct in edittext

Comment: Please click edit and re-write this question from the beginning to present a specific problem you are experiencing in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Why do all that work?  Write a query for the user input login info and if the cursor returned is not empty, you're good to.go.